# Class X is not abstract and does not implement fun writeToParcel() defined in android.os.Parcelable

Tags: android, parcelable, kotlin-android-extensions, android-bundle, kotlinx.serialization

In my Android app, I want to add a Bundle including a `Place` object described below to my Intent. Since serializable was slow and not recommended, I preferred Parcelable.

Althoug I use Kotlin 1.3.31, I have problems parcelizing some data classes. Example:

```
import android.os.Parcelable
import kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize

@Parcelize
data class Place(val street: String, val postal: String, val city: String) : Parcelable
```

and Android Studio complains:

> Class 'Place' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member
>   public abstract fun writeToParcel(p0: Parcel!, p1: Int): Unit defined
>   in android.os.Parcelable

According to some tutorials

> That’s it! You don’t need to write any parcel methods anymore!

https://android.jlelse.eu/yet-another-awesome-kotlin-feature-parcelize-5439718ba220

and I do not want to use

```
androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}
```

in production stuff.

**What alternatives would I have here?**

Comment: Why don't you want to use "experimental = true"? It is a requirement for it to work!

Comment: Most companies do not allow to use experimental features in their apps. JetBrains has to move this out of experimental, and work without

Comment: Check my updated answer! :D

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## UPDATE 19/11/2019

After the stable release of [Kotlin 1.3.60](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2019/11/kotlin-1-3-60-released/) and its corresponding Android Studio plugin the issue is no more.
[Let's celebrate](https://media1.giphy.com/media/ddAGR2jh0FDoY/giphy.gif?cid=790b7611d60f1e74316d6e2154c61dc1ba811b55695dfe2c&rid=giphy.gif)

## UPDATE 27/08/2019

After a bit of more researching and testing with the brand new `Kotlin 1.3.50` seems that the issue is going to be finally fully addressed when they release `Kotlin 1.3.60`  [as per this YouTrack issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-32096)

## EDIT 19/06/2019

With Kotlin 1.3.40 release the `@Parcelize` annotation is out of experimental and works quite nicely. The only issue is a reported [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-19300) that makes the IDE go red, leaving this to a side the code does compile and run perfectly.

[image: Sample code]

[image: Sample code]

[image: Sample code]

I have also tested with this kind of objects and it does also work:

[image]

## Old answer

I'm facing the exact same issue and while investigating I found this:

[image: Jake Wharton on parcelize]

So the looks like the `@Parcelize` annotation will be fully stable starting from `Kotlin 1.3.40`. Until then you will have to set the `experimental` flag. (Sadly)

---

They have wrongly pushed `@Parcelize` outside experimental features and you still get that compilation error.

Comment: (After 19/11/2019 update) - Problem persists for me in 3.5.2 AS + plugin and 1.3.60 kotlin

Comment: For me it works; 
Android Studio 3.5.2
Kotlin plugin version: 1.3.60-release-Studio3.5.1 (Stable update channel)
Android Studio 3.5.2
Build #AI-191.8026.42.35.5977832, built on October 30, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.14.6

Comment: Did all the usual to rule out any caching. Came back to it after lunch and it was fine. Time heals all wounds it seems

Comment: Problem persists for me too in Android Studio version 4.1.3 and Kotlin Version 1.4.32.

Answer (score 4):

In my scenario, I have already used the Kotlin plugin version higher than `1.3.40`.

But I still got the Android Studio Error, **compile success**, **but IDE complaint about the `@Parcelize` annotation**.

Maybe you got this as well.

Here is the solution.

***Check your Kotlin plugin version which you are configured in Gradle is the same version bundled in Android Studio.***

I got the error because my Gradle koltin plugin version is `1.3.61` and the Android Studio bundled version is `1.3.50`

[image]

[image]

How to upgrade the kotlin plugin version？

Tools -> Kotlin -> Configure kotlin plugin update

check the latest version and install it, keep the two versions are the same.

[image]

Comment: To remove the error warning from Android Studio, this worked fine for me. I'm using the version 1.3.60.

Comment: This helps, although in my case I had an old version of Kotlin specified in my Gradle file >_<

Answer (score 0):

You can always just implement Parcelable(cmd+enter/alt+enter on class name -> `Add Parcelable Implementation" in order for IDE to create method schemas for you) if you dont' want to/can't use experimental extensions.

I've, however, been using @Parcelize in prod environment(after a lot of testing though) for over a year, with no issues.(Just an opinion though, not saying you should)